# Is 好 acting as verb complement or adjective in 我穿好衣服了?

Tags: usage, complement

In the sentence

然后，我穿好衣服了。

What's the function of 好?

Is it a complement for the verb 穿 meaning "the act of putting on has finished"?

Or is it an adjective for 衣服 meaning "good clothes"?

Answer (score 5):

> Is it a complement for the verb 穿 meaning "the act of putting on has finished"?

That's exactly that. You can consider it as "done, have completed something".

Following are some common usages:

1. 我吃好了 => I have had enough to eat./I'm full.
2. 我休息好了 => I'm well rested.
3. 我穿好衣服了 => I am done getting dressed.

Here's also an variant.

1. 我吃好了 = 我吃得很好
2. 我休息好了 = 我休息得很好
3. 我穿得很好 is rarely used in Chinese language as it describe the process of the getting dressed is pleasant and enjoyable, or the process is correctly executed/implemented (which is weird).

When you are using this variant, make sure you pick the right 得 character, do not be confused with 的, as the presence of the latter indicates 好 actually describes the quality of the object. 我穿的很好 means **what** I'm wearing is good.

Answer (score 1):

When 好 follows a verb, such as 做好, it functions as an auxiliary verb (like has done, have done) and an adverb (like well, adequately, appropriately).

我穿好衣服了 means I have put on my clothes properly.

This word 好 is used so frequently in the Chinese language that you can not restrict its meanings according to the dictionaries. Under various conditions, it could have a broad spectrum of meanings. In general, it expresses a positive attitude and feeling. For example:

身体好，学习好，工作好。Keep fit, study hard, and work well。